# Team provider 4.0.5 not available while install Subversive

Tags: eclipse, subversive

I run Eclipse Oxygen2 on Ubuntu. I have isntalled Javah:

```
sudo apt-get install libsvn-java
```

Now I try to install `subversive` from market place. Got error:

```
The following solutions are not available: Subversive - SVN Team Provider svn team provider 4.0.5 not available
Proceed with installation anyways?
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Does adding the update site `http://community.polarion.com/projects/subversive/download/eclipse/6.0/neon-site/` (in _Window > Preferences: Install/Update > Available Software Sites_ click _Add..._) fix your issue? See also: http://www.eclipse.org/subversive/installation-instructions.php

Comment: This not helps. If I ignore this message Eclipse installs plugin, but I afraid it might be defective

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue, click not to install anyway on this error and then I install it from Help-->Install New Software... and there I have use "Oxygen - http://download.eclipse.org/releases/oxygen" (that will depends of your Eclipse Version) then search for "Subversive" and install "Subversive SVN Team Provider", "Subversive SVN Team Provider Sources" and "Subversive Revision Graph"

After that restart Eclipse and wait for Eclipse Initialization and It will ask for install SVN connector, I had select SVNKit and install.

It works great for mi, hope it works ;-)